# Why does this expression not unifiy

Tags: prolog, unification

I have defined the following knowledge base:

```
leaf(_).
tree(X) :- leaf(X).
```

and was expecting the query:

```
leaf(X) = tree(X).
```

to return `true .`, because any leaf should per definition be a tree.

Unfortunately activating trace doesn't yield any useful results.
Here is a [link](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/BCEIgklB.pl) to this minimal example if you'd like to play around with it.

Comment: It would help if you explained your logic in coming to this conclusion `in your question`, beyond just `because for any arbitrary value X this equation should hold.` Explain it like you would to someone who doesn't know Prolog. I can easily think of many ways to answer this, but unless I am helping you correct a fault with your understanding of how Prolog executes goals, I will just be taking random guesses. It is a good question, but at present your question can lead to a discussion which will waste my time and your time.

Comment: @GuyCoder thank you very much for this feedback. I hope I have clarified my reasoning.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That possibility was not even on my list.

Comment: Predicates are not functions that return values. So `leaf(X) = tree(X)` does not evaluate `leaf(X)` and `tree(X)` and try to compare them or unify some kind of results. A reasonable query might be, `leaf(X), tree(Y), X = Y`. Your facts, though, aren't completely meaningful. `leaf(_).` means *anything* is a leaf.  For example, `leaf([a,b,foo(x,y),2,3])` succeeds.

Comment: @lurker I know that predicates don't return values, but I was expecting the unification algorithm to figure out that it could substitute `tree` for `leaf` and then unify `leaf(X)=leaf(X)`.

Comment: Unification can only substitute (bind) variables. `leaf` and `tree` are no not variables. They are atoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: you here check if the term `leaf(X)` can be unified with `tree(X)`. Since these are terms that consist out of different functors, this will fail.

The `tree/1` and `leaf/1` in your statement `leaf(X) = tree(X)` are *not* the predicates. What you basically here have written is:

```
=(leaf(X), tree(X))
```

So you call the `(=)/2` predicate, with `leaf(X)` and `tree(X)` terms.

Now in Prolog two terms are *unifiable* if:

1. these are the same atom; or
2. it is a term with the same functor and arity, and the arguments are elementwise unifiable.

Since the functor `leaf/1` is not equal to the functor `tree/1`, this means that `leaf(X)` and `tree(X)` can not be equal.

Even if we would define a predicate with the intent of checking if two predicates are *semantically* the same, this would fail. Here you basically aim to solve the [*Equivalence problem*](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~nelson/courses/csc_173/computability/undecidable.html), which is *undecidable*. This means that one, in general, can not construct an algorithm that verifies if two Turing machines decide the same language. Prolog is a *Turing complete* language, we basically can translate any predicate in a Turing machine and vice versa. So that means that we can not calculate if two predicates accept the same input.

Comment: Or more specifically, I would say "...in Prolog, two terms are *unifiable* if: (1) the terms are the same *atom*, or (2) the terms have the same functor/arity, and the arguments are element-wise *unifiable*". Otherwise, you have to define what you mean by "equivalent" terms.

Comment: @lurker: agreed, that is a better way of specifying it :)